# How to add a button control to an android xml view at runtime?

Tags: android, layout

I have an android xml layout, main.xml. I would like to add controls to this layout at runtime (I would like to add a series of additional linear layouts that contain buttons controls). Can I do that and if yes, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see the error u r doing here

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
```

You r taking the layout as Linearlayout object, you should take the LinearLayout id

Try this

```
LinearLayout lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout01);

Button b1 = new Button(this);

b1.setText("Btn");

lnr.addView(b1);
```

Comment: Yes, but button is not defined in the xml. I want to do the following: Button b = new Button(this); LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main); mainLayout.addView(b), I try this but I get an error. Is this the way to do it?

Comment: What's the error? Have you tried addView(b, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can add controls programmatically if you want in your code, or even another XML with a View and an Inflater.

Here you can read the basics: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: I have read the document but it does not mention how to add new controls (created at runtime) to an existing xml layout file.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I have got it to work.

The steps are the following:
First inflate the xml layout, ie,

```
View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
```

Then instantiate the container object from the xml layout into a ViewGroup class, ie,

```
ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.myContainer);
```

Then create a linearLayout object, create and add onto that any controls needed, add the linearLayout to the container object and use setContentView on the view object, ie,

```
container.addView(buttonsLayout);
this.setContentView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easy by setting an id on the layout on which you want to add views to. Say your main.xml look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Lets assume that you want to add your additional views to the `LinearLayout` with id `id/container`. In your `onCreate` method you could retrieve that object for later use:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContainer = (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.container);
}
```

Now you are all set to add other views to your container `ViewGroup`:

```
LinearLayout theButtons = getButtons()
mContainer.addView(theButtons);
```

In the `getButtons` method you need to create your `LinearLayout` containing the buttons you need. Either you do this programmatically or by inflating a view defined in an XML file. See [`LayoutInflater.inflate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.llmain);
```

now create button dynamically like this

```
 Button btn1 = new Button(this);
 btn1.setText=("Button 1");
 mainLinearLayout .addView(btn1);
```

now if you want to add onether linearlayout then add it below button then

```
 LinearLayout llinner = new LinearLayout(this);

 Button btn2 = new Button(this);
 btn2.setText=("Button 2");
mainLinearLayout .addView(btn2);

llinner.addView(btn2 );

mainLinearLayout .addView(llinner);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this :

```
LinearLayout ll =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linlay);
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setText("Hello");
l.addView(b);
```

> This might help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to display a set of runtime buttons on table layout.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_main, null);
    TableRow myrow = (TableRow) view.findViewById(R.id.myrow);

    Button btn1 = new Button(this);
    btn1.setText("Button 1");
    myrow .addView(btn1);

    Button btn2 = new Button(this);
    btn2.setText("Button 2");
    myrow .addView(btn2);
    this.setContentView(view);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="404dp"
    android:layout_height="691dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/mylayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/myrow"></TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

AVD Pixel4API30

Output screenshot
[image: output of code]