# How do I add a button to a "extends View" class?

Tags: android, button, view, merge, extends

Is it possible to add a button to a class that extends View? ""public class josh extends View "" If not how can I merge a button onto the view when it is referenced in my main activity? uhg please help....

Comment: Do you mean that you're doing all of the drawing yourself in this new View, and you'd like to draw a button over part of it?

Comment: Yes exactly Julian! How can I do this?

Comment: I dont think its possible to draw a button in the (extends View) class.... When I "setContentView" this class can I add a button then? (addContentView(layout, params))  If so how i cant seem to get it right :(   
    
      
    
   }
  });

Comment: try implementing a ViewGroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Have both the button and your custom view as children of a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html), by which the button can be drawn over your custom view.
2. Don't have a real button.  Instead, draw something that looks like a button, treat touch events specially if they're within its dimensions, etc.  This is more appropriate for something like a game.

I believe you can do #2 but have a subclass of Button do the drawing, so that it performs exactly like a normal button and is just positioned/sized by your custom view, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If are wanting to add a button to a view at runtime check this preivoius question... [How to add a button control to an android xml view at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924604/how-to-add-a-button-control-to-an-android-xml-view-at-runtime)

Comment: This adds a View to a ViewGroup.  The OP's class "extends View", so it isn't a ViewGroup.