# Create a button with given width

Tags: java, android, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to add button dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851633/how-to-add-button-dynamically-in-android)

I need to create a button in android without using xml.I have tried the following code:

```
Button b=new Button(this);
b.setWidth(50);
```

However, It isn't displaing in runtime.

Comment: you need to add that `button` in some parent layout that might be `relative` or `linear`.

Comment: give sample code.@PratikSharma

Comment: Go here it will help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924604/how-to-add-a-button-control-to-an-android-xml-view-at-runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the view to the layout before it will be shown on the screen.

```
Button b=new Button(this);
b.setWidth(50);
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

layout.addView(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText("Push Me");
    myButton.height = 60;
    myButton.width = 60;
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```