# how to add a view using layout.adView at runtime

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have a problem during the adding of view in the android game development. I want to add a view after certain point of time. To be more precise when called a particular class. I am doing this game development using LibGDX.
Can anyone say how can i do that.?

Comment: Maybe you could add it initially, and hide it and show it when needed. View.VISIBLE and View.GONE in setVisible method of adView.

Answer (score 0):

[How to add a button control to an android xml view at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924604/how-to-add-a-button-control-to-an-android-xml-view-at-runtime)

And to use android code into libgdx

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

That's all.