# How do I call a custom class in an Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-view

So I have this `DrawAnim.java` class file and I want to use its content inside my `MainAcitivty`. I tried creating an object like this:

```
DrawAnim draw;
```

And in `onCreate` method, I did this:

```
draw.onDraw(); <- I know I have to pass a parameter but don't know what to pass on.
```

Here's my class:

```
public class DrawAnim extends View {

    Bitmap ball;
    int x, y;

    public DrawAnim(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.globe);
        x=0;
        y=0;
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Rect ourRect = new Rect();
        ourRect.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight()/2);

        Paint red = new Paint();
        red.setColor(Color.RED);
        red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(ourRect,red);

        if( x < canvas.getWidth()) {
            x += 10;
        } else{
           x =0;
        }
        if( y < canvas.getHeight()){
           y+=10;
        }else{
            y =0;
        }

        Paint p = new Paint();
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball,x,y,p);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've extended a `View`, so you must use it like any other view, either by adding it programmatically at runtime or using it in a layout.

Comment: What do you mean by adding it programmatically at runtime? Can you give me some example thanks.

Comment: Like how this button is added: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4924755/360211, finding an existing container and calling `.addView` but I'd recommend trying to add it in your layout xml, tell me the package it's in and I'll suggest how you might do that.

Comment: I don't want to add any buttons. I forgot to tell you that, my MainActivty is my splash screen, and I'm trying to create this animation without pressing any buttons.

Comment: Button is just a View, like your class is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to add a view in the code. The following steps should be added to the `onCreate` method of the splash `activity`.

1. Get the Layout where the view will be added to in the code, something like `LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);` (It of course has to be change to your layout and layout-id)
2. Create an instance of the `DrawAnim`
3. Add it to the layout by `linearLayout.addView(drawAnim);`

Hope this gives an idea and helps.

Here is a [link to an animated splashscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184092/how-to-make-an-android-splashscreen-animated) and a link to a [very simple splashscreen](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) just to show some alternatives to adding a view. Although the 2nd one is very limited it has a bit animation and does not delay the start of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it like any other views, pass context to your custom view constructor, set Layout params and add it to the parent view group.

```
DrawAnim draw = new DrawAnim(this); // 'this' as a context in activity
draw.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
parentViewGroup.addView(draw);
```